# No error but explosion not working? - Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

In roblox studio, I wanted to make a button that would make an explosion on a certain tower for a sort of minigame in a gameshow, so I made this code, but for some reason this code dosen't work. It would be appreciated if I could get a solid answer too!

Script:

```
local ClickDetector = script.Parent
ClickDetector.MaxActivationDistance = 10

ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    local Towers = workspace.Towers
    local BT = math.random(1,8)
    local BT2 = BT
    wait(0.2)
    if BT2 == "1" then
        local boom = Instance.new("Explosion")
        boom.Position = Towers.Black.boompart.Position
        boom.Parent = workspace
        
    elseif
        
        BT2 == "2" then
        local boom = Instance.new("Explosion")
        boom.Position = Towers.White.boompart.Position
        boom.Parent = workspace
        
    elseif
        
        BT2 == "3" then
        local boom = Instance.new("Explosion")
        boom.Position = Towers.Blue.boompart.Position
        boom.Parent = workspace
        
    elseif
        
        BT2 == "4" then
        local boom = Instance.new("Explosion")
        boom.Position = Towers.Brown.boompart.Position
        boom.Parent = workspace
        
    elseif
        
        BT2 == "5" then
        local boom = Instance.new("Explosion")
        boom.Position = Towers.Green.boompart.Position
        boom.Parent = workspace
        
    elseif
        
        BT2 == "6" then
        local boom = Instance.new("Explosion")
        boom.Position = Towers.Red.boompart.Position
        boom.Parent = workspace
        
    elseif
        
        BT2 == "7" then
        local boom = Instance.new("Explosion")
        boom.Position = Towers.Pink.boompart.Position
        boom.Parent = workspace
        
    elseif
        
        BT2 == "8" then
        local boom = Instance.new("Explosion")
        boom.Position = Towers.Yellow.boompart.Position
        boom.Parent = workspace
        
    end
    print(BT2)
end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably change this line

```
if BT2 == "1" then
```

to

```
if BT2 == 1 then
```

"1" here is a string because it is within quotation marks. BT2, in this case, is a number. They are stored as two different data types. As such, they are not equal.

Note, if you try:

print("1" == 1)

The output is:
false

See the last sentence in the documentation: https://www.lua.org/pil/3.2.html